# Who dies? (+picture)

Tags: logical-deduction

Do you know who of those two stickmans will die? (spoiler: 'both' is wrong)

The left or the right one? (Maybe this is tricky? ;) )
[image: Who dies puzzle]

Comment: How did you get such a high quality picture?

Comment: Can stickmen swim/float?

Comment: This question is straight out of [here](https://youtu.be/u9ETfAQSOIY?t=12m10s)

Comment: When copying a puzzle from another source, please [provide attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: "Everything that has a beginning, has an end..." ;)

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'll go high-risk here:

> None

Because:

> The left one will fall into the sea from a relatively low height.
>  The right one will have no problem surviving the headshot from a Nerf gun.

Alternatively:

> The two friends playing Nerf have no reason to try and kill each other. Left one will not even fall.